# How to combine observables in angular templates with async?

Tags: angular, typescript

My angular template looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoaded && data$ | async as data">
    ...
    {{data}}
</div>
```

... where isLoaded is a normal boolean, and data$ has type `Observable<IData>`. This works when I have strict options off in tsconfig.json, but fails with the following ts error when they are on:

```
... TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'false | Observable<IData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<null> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Promise<null> | null | undefined'.

3   *ngIf="isLoaded && data$ | async as data"
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know I can combine isLoaded and data$ into a single observable, but that feels like a lot of code for something that is simple (without strict settings). Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not split the conditions into individual `*ngIf`s? You could also use `<ng-container *ngIf=".."></ng-container>` that doesn't add additional elements to the DOM.

Comment: (isLoaded) && (data$ | async as data)

Comment: @MikeOne Doesnt work

Comment: @MichaelD Good suggestion. I'm going with <ng-container>